# Can I implement a method in structure in C?

Tags: c, oop, methods

I want to implement methods in C language.
I know C language doesn't support Object Oriented Programming.
But is there a  way to do it? Or is it can't be done?
Because it need to done by C.

```
struct student
{
    int name;
    int address;

    void speak() 
    {
        /* code */
    }

};

int main()
{

    //code ..

    student.speak();

}
```

This is how my code look like.

Comment: C does not have support for method notation.

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?  Or, your IDE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP used no sleuthing prior to asking.

Comment: @ Sergio - It needs to be done by C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may partially emulate this by using pointer to function.

```
struct student
{
    int name;
    int address;

    void (*speak)();
};

void speak_func() {/*...*/}

int main()
{
  //code ..
  struct student student;
  student.speak = speak_func;

  student.speak();
}
```

Comment: Notice that you won't have a `this` pointer when you use this trick, which renders it mostly useless.

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes. A programmer should declare and pass it directly if needed.

Comment: But this breaks the entire reason why you would use this trick.

Comment: @FUZxxl You can supply 'this' so, no, it doesn't.

Comment: @FUZxxl It doesn't "break", but it makes things to look really ugly.

Comment: @user4419802 -Thank you

Comment: Additionally, your minimal example calls the function with the other fields of the object uninitialized (although it’s effectively static).

Comment: @FUZxxl Python's OOP needs to pass `this` as the first argument of its "methods".

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. You can do some tricks to get a result that looks similar but I don't recommend them. In C, you would just use a function:

```
void speak(struct student *student) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Google for "oop in C" where you'll even find a pdf on the subject. I've done this for years myself.

Comment: @Rob Where exactly is my answer wrong?